# For loop where two values change independently

Tags: java, for-loop, int

I want to write a for-loop in java where I give an initial value for two integers and the loop increases both of them independent of one another. To demonstrate what I mean, I'll show the code that I have already tried:

```
for (int i=0; i<(4);i++){
     for(int y=0; y<(4);y++){
         if(array[i].isNext(array[y])){
             return true;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to compare every possible 'i' with every possible 'y'.

This means that when `i =0`, it is compared to the y values: 0,1,2,3 before it increases itself.

I know my code is completely wrong for this and that the two values in my example increase simultaneously, I was wondering if anyone had any insight.

Seems like my problem is elsewhere in my code, thanks for the advice!

Comment: No. They don't increase simultaneously.

Comment: Your code does what you want.

Comment: your code is perfect

Comment: There's no reason to put `()` around the `4`s (although it's harmless). Other than that, your code does what you say you want.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP's code works.

Comment: You do have mismatched braces, though. Using automatic formatting will help prevent that sort of error.

Comment: Use a debugger, and step through the code line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is called a nested loop. If you follow it through you will see that it works fine. (At least the way you have described the problem.)

```
for(i = 0)     //
    for(y = 0) // (0, 0)
    for(y = 1) // (0, 1)
    for(y = 2) // (0, 2)
    for(y = 3) // (0, 3)
for(i = 1)     //
    for(y = 0) // (1, 0)
    for(y = 1) // (1, 1)
    for(y = 2) // (1, 2)
    for(y = 3) // (1, 3)
for(i = 2)     //
    for(y = 0) // (2, 0)
    for(y = 1) // (2, 1)
    for(y = 2) // (2, 2)
    for(y = 3) // (2, 3)
for(i = 3)     //
    for(y = 0) // (3, 0)
    for(y = 1) // (3, 1)
    for(y = 2) // (3, 2)
    for(y = 3) // (3, 3)
```

Every value of `y` is looped through for every value of `i`.

A simultaneous loop would be, for example:

```
for(int i = 0, y = 0; i < 4 && y < 4; i++, y++) {...}
```

And you get

```
for(i = 0, y = 0)
for(i = 1, y = 1)
for(i = 2, y = 2)
for(i = 3, y = 3)
```